# How do I remove slashes during a select statement

Tags: mysql

Please I am new. I am performing an insert select and I want to remove the slashes in a particular field say field b at the select portion of the query.
eg. insert into mytable(a,b,c) select a, stripslashes(b),c from mysecondtable;

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `REPLACE` like this:

```
insert into mytable(a,b,c) 
select a, REPLACE(b, '\\', '\') as b, c 
  from mysecondtable;
```

The `REPLACE` expression might have to be refined, but I hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), e.g. [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Also consider sanitizing or preparing any input to the SELECT in the calling application before you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

use the SUBSTR function of mysql or do something like this:

"insert into table set value = " . stripslashes('whatever')

Answer (score -1):

Are you doint this with PHP? Then a simple `$fieldB = strip_slashes($_POST['b']);` should do. You should then use `$fieldB` in your query.